# Using a VF inputfield as a variable in a custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am in the process of learning APEX/VisualForce, and I'm working on a VF page that lists out all of the chatter posts from a specific record. Right now, the record that it displays the feed for is hard-coded into the controller like this:

```
global ConnectApi.FeedItemPage getNewsFeed() {
    return ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, 'a00E0000006uAuB');
}
```

I would like to use an inputField on the VisualForce page where the user can input a record's Id, click a button, and have the outputPanel re-render displaying the given record's feed.

I have the button and the re-render working, but I can't figure out how to pass the value from the inputField to a variable in the controller without it having to have a field on an Object in the database.

Additionally, and in a similar vein, I want the outputPanel to render iff the variable (discussed above) is not equal to null, but again, I can't figure out how to reference either another field on the page or the variable on the controller.

Thanks in advance for any help! If you want to see some more code, let me know. Most of it is taken or adapted from a Connect in APEX tutorial found [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/connect-in-apex-pilot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the apex:inputText component
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm

```
<apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!actionMethod}" reRender="theOutputPanel" />

<apex:outputPanel id="theOutPutPanel" rendered="{!inputValue != null}" />....
```

apex:inputField, as you rightly pointed out, is when you want to directly bind to sObject fields in the controller

As for re-rendering, [this one is a great post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html).

Comment: Thanks @techtrekker, that definitely gets me halfway there, but I'm still unsure about assigning the value of the inputText field to a variable in the controller. How can I do this? Thanks again!

Comment: The value="{!inputValue}" is a binding to a controller variable called inputValue. On clicking the button, the controller variable will be populated with the value in the text box on the VF page.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says Unknown property 'DemoController.filtRecs', despite trying with both of the following in the controller: String filtRecs; AND String filtRecs {get; set;} ...

Any idea why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: adding 'global' to the front cleared up the error, thanks again!

Comment: you could also use 'public'. So public String filtRecs { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks again! I've gotten the errors to disappear, but it's still not behaving like I want it to. I'm going to upload it to a new question so that I can share the code.

Comment: If you have a minute, here's a link to the question I posted with the full code: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8670/visualforce-w-custom-controller-not-behaving-as-expected